# OData service does not return custom objects

Tags: entity-framework, odata

Here is what I want to do:

1. I have an existing database from where I need to get data.
2. I created data contracts to map them to respective tables by using Entity Framework.  In my example, I have three tables - tblOrder, tblProduct and tblCustomer.  So I created three data contracts to map to these tables. Entity Framework annotations were added to data contratcs.  I wrote a unit test to test out my data contracts.  Everything works as expected with direct Entity Framework calls.  See unit test 1 below.
3. Added DataServiceKey annotation to each data contract.  And wrap them with OData service by adding an order context and data service svc. See below.
4. Wrote a unit test to access some existing order data via OData sevice.  Problem: OData service only returns non-custom data types on Order object.  It returns null on custome data type fields, such as CustomerInfo and ProductList.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there anything special that I have to do for OData calls to work on objects using EF for retrieval?

---

```
[DataServiceKey("ID")]      
[Table("tblOrder", Schema = "schOnlineSale")]      
public class Order     
{     

     [Column("OrderId"), Key]        
     public int ID { get; set; }

     public string OrderName { get; set; }

     public int CustomerId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
     public virtual Customer CustomerInfo { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
     public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductList{ get; set; }
}

[DataServiceKey("CustomerId")]     
[Table("tblCustomer", Schema = "schOnlineSale")]     
public class Customer    
{

     [Key]
     public int CustomerId{ get; set; }

     [Column("FullName")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string MailingAddress { get; set; }   
     public string City { get; set; }   
     public string State { get; set; }   
     public string ZIPCode { get; set; }   
}

[DataServiceKey("ProductId")]   
[Table("tblProduct", Schema = "schOnlineSale")]    
public class Product    
{

     [Key]
     public int ProductId{ get; set; }

     public int OrderId{ get; set; }

     public string ProductName { get; set; }

     public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }   
}
```

---

```
//OData Service wrapper classes    
public class OrderContext:  DbContext    
{        

     public DbSet<Order> Orders {get; set;}

     public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
}

[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]   
public class OrderDataService : DataService<OrderContext>    
{

        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Orders", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Products", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }

        protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                args.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override OrderContext CreateDataSource()
        {
            var dataSource = new OrderContext();
            dataSource.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return dataSource;            
        }
    }
```

---

```
//Unit Test 1 - Querying via data context directly
public void EFDataContext_GetOrderTest()
{            
    var context = new OrderContext();            
    var list = (from a in context.Orders 
          where a.OrderId == 10 || 
                a.OrderId == 15 ||
                a.OrderId== 20 select a).ToList();

    //CustomerInfo and ProductList values are populated properly
}


//Unit test 2 - Querying via OData Service
public void OData_GetOrderTest()
{
  string uriString = "http://localhost/OrderServices/OrderDataService.svc/Orders(10)";
  Uri serviceUri = new Uri(uriString);
  OrderContext context = new OrderContext(serviceUri);
  context.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
  var orderList = context.Orders;            

  foreach (Order s in orderList)
  {
     TestContext.WriteLine("OrderId=" + s.ID);

     Assert.IsNotNull(s.CustomerInfo);  //CustomerInfo is not returned with OData call
                                  //but it's returned properly with entity framework call.

     foreach (Product p in s.ProductList)
     {
        //ProductList is also not returned with OData Service call,
        //but it is returned properly when accessing through Entity Framework calls     
        //directly
     }

   }            
}
```

---

```
//app.config   
<configuration>    
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="OrderContext" connectionString="a valid connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>    
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

OData (or in this case WCF Data Services client) doesn't lazy load navigation properties (that's what the properties created from relationships are called). You have to ask for it explicitely.

You can do this either up front, through Expand, where you can ask the original query to include the entities on the other side of navigation property. Just add .Expand("Orders") to your query to get the order entities as well as the customers.

You can also do this later through the context.LoadProperty method.

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the fact we're setting ProxyCreationEnabled to false, if we do that in our simple data access unit test, the Orders no longer loads. We've tried using the Expand option already alongside the LazyLoadingEnabled = false, but we're still not getting the Expand, if we turn ProxyCreationEnabled back to true, the URL will no longer even pull up. How can we force EF to load the Orders without turning ProxyCreationEnabled to true?

Comment: Also tried applying this Hotfix but it didn't fix the issue either if I left proxy generation on. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277657

Comment: Can you try to trace the request/response on the wire, using fiddler for example, to see if the response contains the expanded entities (assuming you do use the Expand on the client)?